# Does Kivy support Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have recently installed kivy to start experimenting with GUI libraries but upon testing the 'import kivy', an error pops up specifically the one listed below. If I change my python version to 3.6 (that is the solution posted by others) are there any downsides of doing so, or rather is there a better package for GUI that supports Python 3.7?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".....", line 1, in <module>
    import kivy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'
```

Comment: They mention "Python 2.7 - 3.5 - 3.6 - 3.7" on their website, so it's safe to assume they support `Python 3.7`.

Comment: You've simply not installed the package. If it didn't support Python 3.7, you'd get another error - not an import error.

Comment: Point taken. I will reinstall the package properly thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the supported Python versions in the official Kivy documentation: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/faq.html#does-kivy-support-python-3-x

The latest released Kivy supports Python3.7